# Pictures shifting randomly in UITableView after reloading data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, pfquery

Pictures in my tableView are shifting around and are not being displayed on the correct posts after reloading the tableView. I cannot figure how to fix this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hUbYm.jpg

The image above would be the normal image, however sometimes I get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVEVrm.png

I've also did the prepareForReuse() function in the custom cell class but still doesn't work.

Here is the source code:

```
class UserPostsController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var userPostsTable: UITableView!

    var images : [UIImage] = []
    var descriptions : [String] = []
    var likes : [String] = []
    var dislikes : [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Pacifico", size: 30)!]

        userPostsTable.dataSource = self
        userPostsTable.delegate = self

        let postQuery = PFQuery(className: "Post")
        postQuery.whereKey("userid", equalTo: PFUser.current()?.objectId as Any)
        postQuery.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
            if let posts = objects {
                for post in posts {
                    if let descripiton = post["description"] {
                        self.descriptions.append(descripiton as! String)
                    }
                    if let l = post["likes"] {
                        self.likes.append(l as! String)
                    }
                    if let d = post["dislikes"] {
                        self.dislikes.append(d as! String)
                    }
                    if let imageFile = post["imageFile"] as? PFFile {
                        imageFile.getDataInBackground(block: { (data, error) in
                            if let imageData = data {
                                if let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                                    self.images.append(image)
                                }
                            }
                            self.userPostsTable.reloadData()    
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return images.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = userPostsTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userPostCell", for: indexPath) as? UserPostsTableViewCell {
            cell.descriptionLabel.text = descriptions[indexPath.row]
            cell.numerLikes.text = "\(likes[indexPath.row]) likes"
            cell.numberDislikes.text = "\(dislikes[indexPath.row]) dislikes"
            cell.postImage.image = images[indexPath.row]

            cell.selectionStyle = .none

            return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
```

Comment: Some recommendations: 
1- start using entities instead of 4 arrays
2- dont reload the whole tableview when you finish processing an image, that is probably the least efficient way to do it.

Comment: @MarcioRomeroPatrnogic thanks for the advice, still in the learning process. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you problem is here:

```
if let imageFile = post["imageFile"] as? PFFile {
                    imageFile.getDataInBackground(block: { (data, error) in
                        if let imageData = data {
                            if let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                                self.images.append(image)

                            }

                        }
                        self.userPostsTable.reloadData()    
                    })
```

**You are starting background tasks** to get images data.
**Any of these tasks could finish first**, please debug your array and you might find that the images are not in the desired order.

Here is an **apple sample project** that might help you properly load those images in background.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thanks for the sample, you were right, the problem was when I was getting the images. I solved it by getting the data in the cell, not when loading the view.